# Java's SWT: Setting the size of Group hides its widgets

Tags: java, swt

I want to set a Group with some widgets on it in a GridLayout.
I also want the size of the group component to be of fixed size (250x250) and the widgets on it to accommodate (evenly spaced inside it in two columns).
But when I set the size of the Group, it hides its widgets.

Consider this:

```
public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui g=new Gui();
        g.run();
    }

    private Shell shell;
    private Display display;
    private ChartComposite composite;


    public Gui() {
        display=new Display();
        shell=new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 500);

        Group group=new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        group.setText("Group");
        group.setSize(250,250); // this causes trouble

        GridLayout group_layout=new GridLayout();
        group_layout.numColumns=2;
        group_layout.marginBottom=10;
        group_layout.marginTop=10;
        group.setLayout(group_layout);

        Button b1=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b1.setText("Button1");

        Button b2=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b2.setText("Button2");

        Button b3=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b3.setText("Button3");

        Button b4=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b4.setText("Button4");
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]

But now watch what happens when I relocate the call to `setSize()`:

```
public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui g=new Gui();
        g.run();
    }

    private Shell shell;
    private Display display;
    private ChartComposite composite;

    public Gui() {
        display=new Display();
        shell=new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 500);

        Group group=new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
        group.setText("Group");

        GridLayout group_layout=new GridLayout();
        group_layout.numColumns=2;
        group_layout.marginBottom=10;
        group_layout.marginTop=10;
        group.setLayout(group_layout);

        Button b1=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b1.setText("Button1");

        Button b2=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b2.setText("Button2");

        Button b3=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b3.setText("Button3");

        Button b4=new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
        b4.setText("Button4");

        group.setSize(250,250);  // relocated
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

As I mentioned, I need the size of the Group to be (250x250) **before** adding the widgets, so they would accommodate appropriately, and I can't get this done if `setSize()` hides my widgets.

Comment: Mixing Layouts with setSize never works well

Comment: How else can I set the size of Group?
You're saying a widget with layout is not intended to be resized?

Comment: Yes if you use a Layout you let the Layout calculate the size required. None of my dialogs every has a setSize call just Layouts for everything.

Comment: OK then, I'll try to work without setSize(). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: OK, I just remembered why I was setting the size in the first place: the default size of the Group is 0. So I have to set it to *something*, in order for it to appear. What other option do I have?

Comment: @so.very.tired You need to add a layout to the `Shell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A layout is computed and applied by a call of the composite's `layout()` method. In your first snippet, this is never done. Resizing a composite also triggers a re-layout. That's why the call to `setSize()` in your second snippet triggers the layout. It does not work in your first snippet because the GridLayout is not yet set when you call `setSize()`.

Instead of defering the `setSize()` call, you could as well call `group.layout()` after setting the layout and creating all children.

In UIs that use only layouts instead of absolute positioning, a single call to `shell.pack()` would trigger all layouts recursively.